# Pentaho job failing only when running through control-m

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-design-studio

Pentaho job is failing when run through control-M and completes successfully when run manually on spoon and when run on the same server through a script.

Below is the error:

2023/06/16 10:27:40 - TRANS_SRC_LND - ERROR (version 9.0.0.7-758, build 9.0.0.7-758 from 2020-09-24 04.31.14 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry :
2023/06/16 10:27:40 - TRANS_SRC_LND - ERROR (version 9.0.0.7-758, build 9.0.0.7-758 from 2020-09-24 04.31.14 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2023/06/16 10:27:40 - TRANS_SRC_LND - Unexpected error occurred while launching entry [TR_HSHLD_ADDR.0]
2023/06/16 10:27:40 - TRANS_SRC_LND - org.pentaho.metaverse.impl.MetaverseConfig.getExternalResourceCacheExpireTime()Ljava/lang/String;

Can anyone help me what the above error signifies?

I am expecting job to complete successfully when run through external source